# How to make my 4 articles (2 columns) have equal height?

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

Please take a look:  http://jsfiddle.net/mdermez32/vTynd/

HTML:

```
<table class="art-article" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
<col width="50%" />
<col width="50%" />
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><table class="metaart"  width="100%" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlebox" align="justify" background="./images/backgroundxa.png"; style="text-align:left" scope="col"><span style="text-align:left;"><span style="color:rgb(61,60,51);"><span style="font-size:20px;">LOREM </span></span><span style="color:rgb(235, 81, 5);"><a href="./services/operating-systems.html"><span style="color:rgb(61,60,51);"><span style="font-size:20px;">IPSUM</span></span></a><span style="color:rgb(61,60,51);"><span style="font-weight:normal;"><span style="font-size:20px;"><span ;">; </span></span></span></span></span></span><span style="font-size:20px;"></span></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td> <img src="./images/win7-logo.jpg" width="100%" style="border-top-width:0;border-right-width:0;border-bottom-width:0;border-left-width:0;"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><p style="font-size:12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                            <p style="text-align:right"><strong><a href="./services/operating-systems.html"><img src="./images/mores.png" width="119" height="32" alt="Διαβάστε περισσότερα" style="border:0;"/></a></strong></p></td>
                          </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
            <td> <table class="metaart"   width="100%" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlebox" align="justify" background="./images/backgroundxa.png" ; style="text-align:left" scope="col"><span style="text-align:left;"><span style="color:rgb(61,60,51);"><span style="font-size:20px;">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</span></span><span style="color:rgb(235, 81, 5);"><span style="color:rgb(61,60,51);"><span style="font-weight:normal;"><span style="font-size:20px;"><span ;"> </span></span></span></span></span></span></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td> <img src="./images/ubbuntu.jpg" width="100%" style="border-top-width:0;border-right-width:0;border-bottom-width:0;border-left-width:0;"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><p style="font-size:12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
                            <p style="text-align:right"><strong><a href="./services/operating-systems.html"><img src="./images/mores.png" width="119" height="32" alt="Διαβάστε περισσότερα" style="border:0;"/></a></strong></p></td>
                          </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp; </td>
          <td>&nbsp; </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><table class="metaart"  width="100%" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlebox" align="justify" background="./images/backgroundxa.png" ; style="text-align:left" scope="col"><span style="text-align:left;"><span style="color:rgb(61,60,51);"><span style="font-size:20px;">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR</span></span><span style="color:rgb(235, 81, 5);"><span style="color:rgb(61,60,51);"><span style="font-weight:normal;"><span style="font-size:20px;"><span ;"> </span></span></span></span></span></span></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td> <img src="./images/brands.jpg" width="100%" style="border-top-width:0;border-right-width:0;border-bottom-width:0;border-left-width:0;"/></td>
                            </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><p style="font-size:12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                            <p style="text-align:right"><strong><a href="./services/laptop.html"><img src="./images/mores.png" width="119" height="32" alt="Διαβάστε περισσότερα" style="border:0;"/></a></strong></p></td>
                          </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table></td>
          <td><table class="metaart" padding=10px;  width="100%" border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="titlebox"  align="justify" background="./images/backgroundxa.png" ; style="text-align:left" scope="col"><span style="text-align:left;"><span style="font-size: 20px; color: rgb(61,60,51)">LOREM IPSUM DOLOR </span></span></th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td> <img src="./images/farmacy.jpg" width="100%" style="border-top-width:0;border-right-width:0;border-bottom-width:0;border-left-width:0;"/></td>
                                </tr>
                            <tr>
                          <td><p style="font-size:12px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam</p>
                            <p style="text-align:right"><strong><a href="./services/medical-software.html"><img src="./images/mores.png" width="119" height="32" alt="Διαβάστε περισσότερα" style="border:0;"/></a></strong></p></td>
                          </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    </table></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table><br />

                </div>
                <div class="cleared"></div>
                </div>
```

The css code for the shadow effect and the gradient in the title is in the css section at the btm.

What I am trying to do is to make my tables have equal height. As you can see the height of the right tables/cell is smaller than the left ones.

Second question.. where should I put code for padding in order to increase the space between text and it's box.

Answer (score 0):

put the tables in 1 table  or re organized into one table where table 1 is first column etc.